# Header set Content-Security-Policy not handling multiple domains correctly

Tags: xss, apache

I'm trying to protect from XSS attacks under Apache setting the following directive:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' code.jquery.com;"
```

to only allow the jquery.com CDN which is quite handy.
However the directive keeps giving me in Firefox the following:

> The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self
>   ("script-src http://www.website.com http://code.jquery.com").

Answer (score 2):

This is a formatting mistake. 
instead of "code.jquery.com" type in the url containing the http://
like this: http://code.jquery.com
A useful tip: you can use wildcard * for domain name prefix if you need it
like this: http://*.jquery.com, or *.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

it's not good answer in my opinion, we can read on https://content-security-policy.com/
that :
Allow Google Analytics, Google AJAX CDN and Same Origin
script-src 'self' [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) ajax.googleapis.com;

so there's no https://ajax.googleapis.com, it's just domain name.

Correct answer is - add script-src block:
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' code.jquery.com; script-src 'self' code.jquery.com;"